# Scipy Differential Evolution Failed After Adding Constraints

Tags: python, scipy, differential-evolution

I'm trying to run an optimization with scipy.optimize.differential_evolution. I want to find the best weights combination for like 20 variables to find the maximized Spearman Correlation between the calculated total score and a pre-determined rank. As the total weights should be approximately 100%, I need to add constraints to DE. After reading several posts my code is like this

```
def spearman(x):
    if 0.9999 < sum(x) < 1.0001:
        model_score = np.dot(factor, x)
        corr = spearmanr(rank, model_score).correlation
        return corr
    else:
        return 999

bound = [(0.00, 0.15), ..., (0.00, 0.15)]  # bounds for each weights

res = differential_evolution(spearman, bound)
```

However, DE only runs one iteration and returns a "successful" result of 999. Feels like DE considers 999 to be the best solution and stop searching for better one.

I tried another hack by changing the target to minimize “Spearman Correlation + abs(total weights - 1)” at the same time and can get right answer. But I still want to use the "if-else" way to define constraints and get the spearman correlation directly.